# How is Karin's technique similar to Kushina's?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto* chapter 663, Orochimaru mentioned that

> the technique used by Karin to defeat the wooden statue is similar to that of from Kushina (both Uzumaki).
>
>  [image: the manga panel in which Orochimaru stated that]

What is this technique and *how does this work*? Can Naruto (as Uzumaki) use this technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Karin and Kushina both belonged to Uzumaki Clan.It's a type of Hiden Ninjustu.

Although the name of the jutsu is not mentioned clearly but when I explored more I came to know that:-

> Kushina also possessed a powerful and special form of chakra, which made her well-suited for becoming the Nine-Tails' jinchūriki. With her chakra, Kushina was able to materialise chakra chains with which she was able to restrain and subdue the Nine-Tails, both in the real world as well as in her subconscious

1.**What is this technique and how does this work**
To know more about **chakra chains** visit [**here**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Chains)

> Known by members of the Uzumaki Clan, this technique moulds the user's chakra into chains which, after materialising, can be used for various purposes such as physically restraining targets, fight them directly or be used as a means of transportation.

Please do visit here too:-[**Chakra Chains classification**](http://naruto.wikia.com/index.php?title=Special:Ask&offset=0&limit=500&q=%5B%5BConcept:Jutsu%5D%5D%5B%5BUser%20tech::Karin%5D%5D&po=?Appears%20in=Media%0A?Jutsu%20classification=Classification%0A?Chakra%20Nature%0A?Jutsu%20class%20type=Class%0A?Jutsu%20range=Range)

---

2.**Can Naruto use this technique?**
Naruto **did use this technique** during his training under Bee
[image: Naruto Using Chakra Chains]

Comment: While Naruto was training under bee in that island, he didnt use the technique but rather, his mothers chakra which was still sealed inside him performed the technique. Remember that he met his mother shortly afte that and she helped him in taming kurama